# Is it possible to remove "Login as other user" permission for system administrator profile?

Tags: profile, configuration, user-admin

Is it possible to remove "Login as other user" permission for system administrator profile?
I thought to clone sys admin profile and give delegated administrator access, but i dont want to create a new profile.

Is it possible?